# Passing variable to firestore where query (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to query a schedule collection where a field in the document = the users id, but i am getting this error: "Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined."

```
     userId;
     uid;
     sched: Observable<ScheduleModel[]>;
```

The ngOnInit()

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.uid = user.uid;
    });
    this.getSched();
  }
```

```
getSched() {
  this.sched = this.afs.collectionGroup<ScheduleModel>('schedule', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', this.uid)).valueChanges();
}
```

this.uid in the query is giving me the trouble but:

1. When i put the actual user uid 'iq6DkETjgMSMIdxw9cvLEzbf9Fr2' rather than this.uid, it works.
2. In my template file when i put use {{ uid }} and it prints the correct id, so it is not actually undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ngOnInit() {
let self = this;
this.userId = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
  self.uid = user.uid;
});
this.getSched();
}
```

`this` in your `this.uid` is not in the same scope as you were using `{{uid}}`

Comment: try the same thing with `getSched()` below, declare something like `let self = this` and use `self.uid`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still did not work, but you are correct about the scope. I created an alert box with the uid value and it gets displayed as 'Undefined' but then it still shows up in the view. I tried moving it to constructor with the same result.

Comment: @balance85 well, atleast we know what is the problem now

Comment: Ah.. I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.userId = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    this.uid = user.uid;
    **this.sched = this.afs.collectionGroup<ScheduleModel>('schedule', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', this.uid)).valueChanges();
  });
```

moving the assignment of **this.sched seemed to do the trick.